# Getting 'not authorized' while creating MQ subs via command line

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to create IBM MQ subs via command line on a linux installation and I get:

```
AMQ8135: Not authorized.
```

My logs show:

```
AMQ8009: Entity '' has insufficient authority to access topic string 'WW/XX/YY'.
EXPLANATION: The specified entity is not authorized to access the required topic.
The following permissions were requested: altusr/ctrl
```

It looks like the command line isn't getting the entity value from where ever it was trying to find, not sure where that is!

But the confusing part is that creating of other mq objects(queues/topics) work just fine on command line and even the create subs works from MO71 and failing on cmd.

File permission look good and env variable also looked fine to me unless!

```
cmd-  DEFINE SUB('ABC.1') TOPICSTR('xx/yy/zz') DEST('lq.abc')
```

Anyone one ran into such/fixed such issue?

Comment: What does the `AMQERR01.LOG` show at the time you get the `AMQ8135` error.   There should be more to the `AMQ8009` error than you pasted.

Comment: Normally the `AMQ8009` error in the `AMQERR01.LOG` still tell you both the topic that you lack authority to as well as the permission you are lacking.   My guess would be you need sub authority.

Comment: What tool are you using to issue MQSC command, e.g. `runmqsc`? What env variable are you referring to? What version of IBM MQ?

Comment: JoshMC- 
here's my log - 03/09/2020 10:31:55 AM - Process(93102.236) User(mqm) Program(amqzlaa0) VRMF(8.0.0.9) QMgr(Qmgr1) AMQ8009: Entity '' has insufficient authority to access topic string 'WW/XX/YY'. EXPLANATION: The specified entity is not authorized to access the required topic. The following permissions were requested: altusr/ctrl

Comment: 8.0.0.9 there are a number of fixed included related to user authentication (CONNAUTH) and CHLAUTH rules.  I would suggest you update to 8.0.0.14 the latest or better yet move to the latest 9.0 or 9.1 (8.0 goes out of support at the end of April 2020).  This may not resolve the issue but would at least rule out any of the changes made since 8.0.0.9.

Answer (score 2):

In order to successfully run a `DEFINE SUB` command, the user ID that you are running it with requires the following authorities (you can work these out from looking at the whole of the `AMQ8009` message in your `AMQERR01.LOG`, specifically the EXPLANATION: section).

- `ctrl` on the nearest administrative topic object
- `put` on the named destination queue

Also read

- [IBM Knowledge Center: Authorizations for commands](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083530_.htm)
- [IBM Knowledge Center: MQSUB - Usage Notes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101930_.htm) (for authority for output - `put` - needed for subscription)

As an example, let's assume:-

- `TOPIC(XYZ)` is defined with `TOPICSTR('xx/yy/zz')`
- `QUEUE(LQ.ABC)` exists
- The non-privileged user ID running the command is a member of the group `mqgemadm`

Then you need to set the following two privileges (over and above whatever you might have already set for this group in order to be able to issue commands in general):-

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(XYZ)    OBJTYPE(TOPIC) GROUP('mqgemadm') AUTHADD(ctrl)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(LQ.ABC) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mqgemadm') AUTHADD(put)
```

If you believe that your user id already has these permissions and the reason it is failing is because the user id is not making it to the command, you could try adding the `SUBUSER` field to the command.

```
DEFINE SUB('ABC.1') TOPICSTR('xx/yy/zz') DEST(LQ.ABC) SUBUSER('mqgemusr')
```

If this works, but without `SUBUSER` still fails, suggest you report the defect to IBM via a PMR/support case.

Comment: Excellent answer as always. Did you find `ctrl` documented in the KC for this purpose or was this just by trail and error knowledge? (Ex looking at the whole AMQ8009 error message)

Comment: I did it by looking at my own `AMQERR01.LOG` using a non-privileged user id. It is documented in KC as well, so I have added the link for use of `ctrl` on topics.

Comment: Hello Morgan, thanks for answering.
Not sure If this could be user access coz it should'nt work on MO71 either right? But it does :(
I tried updating the auth like you suggested, unfortunately no success

here's my log -

03/09/2020 10:31:55 AM - Process(93102.236) User(mqm) Program(amqzlaa0)
             
                    VRMF(8.0.0.9) QMgr(Qmgr1)
AMQ8009: Entity '' has insufficient authority to access topic string
'WW/XX/YY'.
EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required topic. The
following permissions were requested: altusr/ctrl

Comment: @KrishnaKondapalli - Did you try passing the user id in on the `SUBUSER` field as I suggested? Could you also tell us what tool you are using, is it runmqsc? MO71 uses PCF, but we don't know what you are using to be able to comment on the difference between it and MO71. Also could you tell us what version of MQ? And what env var you are talking about.